# Unable restart the hive after installation of Apache Ranger

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-ranger

I recently installed apace Ranger and Enabled the hive plugins.when try to restart the Effected components at hive got the following error

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/config_dictionary.py", line 73, in __getattr__
raise Fail("Configuration parameter '" + self.name + "' was not found in configurations dictionary!")
```

resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Configuration parameter 'REPOSITORY_CONFIG_USERNAME' was not found in configurations dictionary!

Answer (score 0):

Set REPOSITORY_CONFIG_USERNAME=hive in custom-ranger-hive-plugin-properties